# Cannot access bundle.js, when url is multiple layers deep

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

`bundle.js` works on `localhost:3000/abc` (because it looks in the `localhost:3000/assets` folder), but if I go to `localhost:3000/abc/xyz` I get a `404` (because it looks in the `localhost:3000/abc/assets` folder).

My `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets/",
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "./dist",
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] 
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'javascript/auto',
                test: /\.html/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I cannot use an absolute path for the `publicPath`. 
How can I access `bundle.js` when I am multiple layers deep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `index.html` I had

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/bundle.js"></script>
```

All I had to do is to change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bundle.js"></script>
```